A surface with a local max is tangent to a sphere

Let $S \subset \Bbb{R}^3$ a regular surface and $F : S \rightarrow \Bbb{R}, p \mapsto d(p,O)$ where $O$ is the origin. If $p \in S$ is a local maximum of $F$ , then $S$ is tangent to $S_R(O)$ : the sphere centered in the origin of radius $R= F(p)$ .

I am trying to prove this but I am not sure on how to do it.
My first thought was to prove that $S \cap S_R(O) = \{p\}$ and in order to do it, we could use the hypothesis $\exists \varepsilon > 0 \, \forall p' \in B(p,\varepsilon) \cap S : F(p') \leq F(p)$ .
If for all $p' \neq p$ it occurs that $F(p') < F(p)$ then $p' \notin S_R(O)$, which implies what we want to prove. But I think that this is not necessarily true.
On the other hand, as $p$ is local maximum, we have that taking $\varphi : U \subset \Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S$ a chart around $p$ and $G:= F \circ \varphi $ we would have that $G_{uu} (p) < 0$ and $G_{uu}(p) G_{vv}(p) - G_{uv} (p) > 0$, but I am not seeing how to use this to prove the result, so any possible help would be appreciated.

This is just a particular case of constrained optimization. If you lookup the method of Lagrange multipliers, where the candidates to extrema satisfy the relation $\nabla F = \lambda \nabla g$ (assuming that the surface, or restriction, is represented by $g(x,y,z) = 0$), you'll find what you need.

What is the definition of tangent that you are using?

@ArcticChar In my course notes there is not defined what means that two surfaces are tangent. I have assumed that it means that their intersection is unique or that they both have a point of each other in their tangent planes respectively.

I’m assuming by tangent you mean that there is an open ball around $p$ in which the surface $S$ is always on one side of $S_R(O)$ and they intersect in at least one point. Let’s prove this.
Since $p$ is a local maximum, there is an open neighbourhood $U\subset S$ of $p$ such that $F(q) \le F(p)$ for all $q\in U\setminus\{p\}$. Let $B \in \mathbb R^3$ be the ball centred at $p$, such that $B\cap S \subseteq U$. Then, $(B\cap S)\cap (B\cap S_R(O)) \ni \{p\}$ and the remaining points in $B\cap S$ are either closer to the origin than the points in $B\cap S_R(O)$ or they are on $B\cap S_R(O)$. So $B\cap S$ is always on the inner side of $B\cap S_R(O)$ and they intersect in at least one point, namely, $p$. So $S_R(O)$ is tangent to $S$ at $p$.

If tangent means to intersect only at one point, then the statement in the OP is not true. Here’s a counterexample. Let $S$ be an oblate spheroid, i.e., a flattened sphere, where the flattened direction is $z$ axis. Then, every point on the equator of $S$ (which is in the $xy$ plane) is a local maximum. And the sphere $S_R(O)$ intersects $S$ exactly along the equator of $S$. (Personally, I would still call this tangent.)

Thanks for your answer. I am missing something: why are all the points in $B \cap S_R (O)$ farther from $O$ than all points in $B \cap S$ except $p$ ?

@Superdivinidad Because for any $p\ne q\in B\cap S \subseteq U$ we have $F(q) < F(p) = R$, whereas any point in $B\cap S_R(O)$ is by definition at a distance $R$ from the origin.

But, in that open neighbourhood there can be a point $q \neq p$ such that $d(q,O) = d(p,O)$, right? The definition I know says that $p$ is local maximum iff on some open neighbourhood $F(q) \leq F(p)$, what does not take away that maybe some $q$ satisfies $F(q) = F(p)$

@Superdivinidad Okay got it. I updated the answer accordingly

Why the point in $B \cap S$ are either closer to the origin than the points in $B \cap S_R (O)$ ? Sorry if I am asking so much, I think that they can be at the same distance

@Superdivinidad if they are at the same distance, then they are on $B\cap S_R(O)$, which is included in my answer.

But this means that $ ( B \cap S ) \cap ( B \cap S_R(O) ) $ is not a single point, so there would not be tangent

@Superdivinidad What exactly is your definition of tangent then? I explained what my definition is at the beginning of my answer. If that’s not your definition, then the statement in the OP is not true and it’s very easy to construct counterexamples.

It is impossible to give an answer if you don't have a definition, @Superdivinidad

I just want to point out that the definition in this answer does not include that the tangent plane of some saddle point.

@ArcticChar you are right. My definition matches with the usual one when the point is not a saddle point.
